# missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c, dll, code-injection, inject

I have been trying to solve that problem on these code stacks. I tried to block injection etc. on my executable.

I call my function like that:

```
#include "Protect.h"

EL_DenyProcessAccess();
```

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'EL_DenyProcessAccess'

```
#pragma once

#include "AccCtrl.h"
#include "Aclapi.h"

BOOL EL_FORCEINLINE EL_DenyProcessAccess( void )
{
    BYTE    abyBuffer[0x200];
    PACL    pACL;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY stIdentifierAuthority = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    PSID pSid = NULL;
    BOOL bRet = FALSE;
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    HANDLE hProcess = ::GetCurrentProcess();
    PTOKEN_USER pUserInfo = NULL;

    if( ::AllocateAndInitializeSid( &stIdentifierAuthority, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pSid ) == FALSE )
        goto Cleanup;
    if( ::OpenProcessToken( hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken ) == FALSE )
        goto Cleanup;
    ::GetTokenInformation( hToken, TokenUser, NULL, NULL, &dwSize );
    if( dwSize > 1024 )
        goto Cleanup;
    pUserInfo = (PTOKEN_USER) ::GlobalAlloc( GPTR, dwSize );
    if( pUserInfo == NULL )
        goto Cleanup;
    if( ::GetTokenInformation( hToken, TokenUser, pUserInfo, dwSize, &dwSize ) == FALSE )
        goto Cleanup;
    pACL = (PACL) &abyBuffer;
    if( ::InitializeAcl( pACL, 0x200, ACL_REVISION ) == FALSE )
        goto Cleanup;
    // Deny except PROCESS_TERMINATE and PROCESS_SET_SESSIONID
    if( ::AddAccessDeniedAce( pACL, ACL_REVISION, PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS | PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD, pSid ) == FALSE )
        goto Cleanup;
    // Allow SYNCHRONIZE, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION, PROCESS_SET_QUOTA and PROCESS_TERMINATE
    if( ::AddAccessAllowedAce( pACL, ACL_REVISION, SYNCHRONIZE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION | PROCESS_SET_QUOTA | PROCESS_TERMINATE, pUserInfo->User.Sid ) == FALSE )
        goto Cleanup;
    if( ::SetSecurityInfo( hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 0, 0, pACL, 0 ) != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        goto Cleanup;
    bRet = TRUE;
Cleanup:
    if ( hToken )
        ::CloseHandle( hToken );
    if ( pSid )
        ::FreeSid( pSid );
    return bRet;
}
```

I can't see any error on my code?

Comment: Is that "call" in the global scope? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And unrelated to your problem, but that's a pretty massive function to have inline in a header file.

Comment: You cannot call a function in the global space unless you are assigning the return of the function to a global variable.

Comment: @Liveth Your C++ code looks a lot like C code.

Comment: Yes, it's is C, my fault.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm trying to call from Protect.h header, in my main.cpp I tried to add some includes (as I see microsoft threads) but it didn't work.

Comment: I would say that one of `BOOL` or `EL_FORCEINLINE` isn't defined.

Comment: ***Where*** is the call to the function? Is it inside a function? Is it outside any functions? Please create an MCVE and show us or we will only be guessing (which we don't like to do, and rather vote to close the question).

Comment: You cannot call in a .h file. Calling starts in main. You may have seen a macro, but it won't expand to a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is apparently considered as C++ by the compiler. This is the reason you get an error.

The problem is that BOOL and EL_FORCEINLINE are not defined. 
So the preprocessor translates

```
BOOL EL_FORCEINLINE EL_DenyProcessAccess( void )
```

into

```
EL_DenyProcessAccess( void )
```

You should make sure that BOOL is defined.

In C the type `int` is assumed when no return type is specified. It might be the desired behaviour of the author, but it's error prone.

Comment: BOOL EL_DenyProcessAccess( void ) works well. Thank you.